# Multisite - One user allowed access to all sites?

Tags: multisite, users

I am creating a multisite environment where each site is a classroom blog in the same school.  Is it possible to create one parent user with access to all sites?  That way parents don't have to keep logging in if they have students in different classrooms.

If that is possible, the next question is, can I set up that parent user account with editor access on all sites?  Or read-only access?

I can't be the first person to create a group of classroom blogs like this.  Any general advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that you will be forced to login on every site, since every site uses its own set of database tables and so on.

Comment: @KristerAndersson as far as I remember users is one of the things that is shared in multisite in database and logically

Comment: @Rarst - Just looked at my multisite installations database and you're absolutely right, didn't know that.

Comment: Such a system raises privacy concerns that a parent will be able to access the site of another child they are unrelated to. There are legal concerns in many countries around data protection

Comment: Good point on the privacy issue.  I believe the intention of the individual blogs will be general information about events, etc. and not personal student information.  But that should be clarified before moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the `Wordpress MU Domain Mapping` plugin. I've just tested this and it seems to work if I go to the `main` site and login I'm then logged in on all the sub sites.

I think you might need to tweek the `domain options` for the plugin under `wp-admin/network/settings.php?page=dm_admin_page` for this to work.

***Reference***

[WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

[Single Sign On to all sites in my entire WP Network](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/single-sign-on-to-all-sites-in-my-entire-wp-network)